# Resize metadata navigation pane

Tags: navigation, metadata

I have a basic list with metadata navigation enabled on the quick launch. The navigation pane on the left side of the list and it's resizable. How can I resize this or, an even better solution, auto resize?

[image: Metadata]

Answer (score 1):

I guess its a bit late, but whatever. This article seems to be an answer.
http://www.arkaden.ch/Blog/Beitrag/11/Customize-keyfilter-and-treeview-navigation-bar-with-dragable-border
At least, it works for me (sharepoint 2013 on-premise)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to place the pointer directly on the border between the managed metadata navigation and then the cursor changes to an error. Grab the border and move it to the left and to the right.

[image: Drag the border to resize]

Sadly this will not be automatically resized but I think it can be done by using jquery.

Comment: Unfortunately my users want this to be done automatically or at least big enough to display all the text without expanding it themselves.  Users eh.

Comment: An easy trick would be if you change the width of the navigation using css but this will change it everywhere in your portal then. Let me know if I can help you with this.

Comment: A css script would be great if you can help.  I use the same master page for a sites so I'm guessing that I will need to specify a different one for this site.

Comment: Stefan Do you have the code you can send me to resize the panel?  Where do I put the code?  MAsterpage?

Comment: Mike: Hope I still have it somewhere. Will check if I can find something for you.

Comment: Hi Stefan did you have any luck finding the code?